# Dropzone Accepted Files Issue

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I have set Dropzone to only allow PDfs

```
acceptedFiles: "application/pdf"
```

However whenever I upload a PDF it throws an error. In the response it is stating that the file I tried uploading was an unkown file type.

```
type: "unknown/data"
```

I am not sure how to handle this or fix it. I have tried multiple PDF files from all different sources.

Comment: Could you share some more code or even a working fiddle?

Answer (score 11):

try this...

```
acceptedFiles: ".pdf"
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
maxFiles: 5,

maxFilesize: 20,

acceptedFiles: "image/*,application/pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.csv,.tsv,.ppt,.pptx,.pages,.odt,.rtf",
```

Comment: Are the first two lines important? If so what effect do they have on the question? How will the third line help to solve the problem? "Try this" answers need to explain how and why the person proposing them thinks it will help, otherwise they are comments and not answers.

Comment: No, first two lines are not important.